# Convert high resolution clock time into an integer (Chrono)

Tags: c++

I want to be able to get nanosecond accuracy with the chrono library but I can't figure out how to convert `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` into `long int`. I tried this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

    long int val = Clock::now();

    cout << val << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

But this gave me the error: `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::chrono::system_clock::time_point' to 'long'`
How can I convert it to a 64 bit int? If I can't then I don't see how chrono is useful.

Comment: If you read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now) you will see that the `now` function returns a [`time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) object (just like the error message says). See the `time_point` link for an example on how to print the time. If you want the time in seconds, use e.g. [`to_time_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t).

Comment: One of `<chrono>`s advantages is that it is type safe; two examples are that time points and time durations are distinct, non-interchangeable types and the types keep track of units for you, so you can't confuse seconds for milliseconds, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following works with GCC 4.8 on Linux:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto now = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto nanos = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count();
std::cout << nanos << '\n';
```

Comment: This printed out a huge negative number.

Comment: @SusanYanders I don't think count can return a negative

Comment: @aaronman Hmm thats strange my code was almost exactly the same yet it printed out what I expected when I tried your code. Anyways thanks

Comment: @SusanYanders: Beware that `long int` isn't necessarily 64 bits; it's 32 on at least one popular platform. Use `auto` or `std::uint64_t` to be sure the type is large enough.

Comment: One of `<chrono>`s advantages is that it is type safe; two examples are that time points and time durations are distinct, non-interchangeable types and the types keep track of units for you, so you can't confuse seconds for milliseconds, etc. Stick with `<chrono>` types as long as possible and only convert to generic types like `long` as late as possible. For example: `auto nanos = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()); std::cout << nanos.count() << '\n';` instead of doing the `.count()` when initializing `nanos`.

Answer (score 5):

First, convert the time point returned by `now()` into the duration since a known timepoint. This can either be the clock's epoch:

```
auto since_epoch = Clock::now().time_since_epoch();
```

or some timepoint that you've chosen:

```
auto since_epoch = Clock::now() - my_epoch;
```

Then you can get the number of nanoseconds either by converting and extracting the count:

```
auto nanos = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(since_epoch).count();
```

or by dividing by whatever granularity you want:

```
auto nanos = since_epoch / nanoseconds(1);
```

<sub>As noted in the comments, only do this last conversion (which leaves the Chrono library's type system, losing valuable information about what the number means) if you really need a scalar quantity; perhaps because you're interacting with an API that doesn't use the standard types. For your own calcuations, the types should allow you to perform any meaningful arithmetic that you need.</sub>

Comment: `auto nanos = since_epoch / nanoseconds(1);` It should be pointed out that this results in a unitless scalar. Unless you actually need a unitless value then it's best to stick with chrono's unit-safe types.

Comment: @bames53: Indeed; but in this case, a unitless scalar is exactly what the OP is asking for, and exactly what `count()` also gives you.

Comment: Sure but new users ought to be informed about the benefits of strong typing in the context of `<chrono>` and shown idiomatic `<chrono>` usage. New users often ask for weaker types simply because that's what they're used to in other time libraries, not because they actually need weak types.

Comment: @bames53: I suppose you're right. A lecture on type safety is rather off-topic for this question, but I've added a brief one in case anyone reads the answer and thinks that leaving the type system sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

A more succinct version of nosid's answer:

```
long int time = static_cast<long int>(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count());
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a std::chrono::duration_cast:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast

Comment: This is not a full explanation, the part that actually converts it to an int is the `count` call